# Perl, Why it has a extra white space in output

Tags: perl

input:

[image]

output:

[image]

but my out put have one extra white space on last two line.
my output:

[image]

my code:

```
@content = <FILE>; 

foreach $line (@content){ 
    if($line =~ /^#(\d+)/){ 
        $number = $1; 
        $line =~ s/^#(\d+)/$content[$number-1]/; 
    }
    print "$line"; 
}
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: my code:@content = <FILE>;

foreach $line (@content){
 if($line =~ /^#(\d+)/){
  $number = $1;
  $line =~ s/^#(\d+)/$content[$number-1]/;
 }
 print "$line";
}

Comment: Idk why the output have extra white space

Comment: Please edit your question and enter text (for input, output, and code) instead of images.  If formatting is a problem there are detailed instructions on help pages (and I'll help now).  I took care of the code you showed in the comment.

Comment: By extra whitespace, do you mean the newlines your substitution ends up doubling up?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Why do people thing that's useful? Please edit your question and replace the images with actual text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version of your code with sample input data. If you want people to help you with problems like this, then it's a good idea to make it as easy as possible for them. Posting images of your input data does not make it easy. Also, it's a good development trick to store sample data in the `DATA` filehandle so that the code and data are together in the same file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @content = <DATA>;

foreach my $line (@content){
    if($line =~ /^#(\d+)/){
        my $number = $1;
        $line =~ s/^#(\d+)/$content[$number-1]/;
    }
    print "$line";
}

__DATA__
line A
line B
line C
#7
line D
#2
line E
```

I've also added `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code. In this case, they don't really help, but you should get into the habit of always including them in your Perl programs.

Your problem is here:

```
$line =~ s/^#(\d+)/$content[$number-1]/;
```

Each of the lines in your `@content` array will include a newline character at the end. But in this line you're replacing the `#` symbol and the following digit with a complete other line from the array. You're not replacing the original newline and you're adding another newline (from the replacement string) so the line ends up containing two newlines.

The easiest fix is to add the newline to the pattern you are matching.

```
$line =~ s/^#(\d+)\n/$content[$number-1]/;
```

Note that an experienced Perl programmer would write your code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @content = <DATA>;

for (@content){
    s/^#(\d+)\n/$content[$1 - 1]/;
    print;
}
```